# After adding .edmx file what is the need to add `Code generation item`?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have working on mvc3 application.

I want to know some specific answer about :

> After adding .edmx file what is the need to add `Code generation item` like
>   Poco , dbContext etc.

Please explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code generation items will give you POCOs.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456853.aspx

It will create objects (classes) that you can then use in your application.

This article is really useful to help you create POCOs using dbcontext tt.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/03/15/ef-4-1-model-amp-database-first-walkthrough.aspx

Comment: Its not necessary. You can create your own classes that you can use. But this tt will do this for you modeled after the tables in your database. In other words it will do the work for you each time you add or remove a table, just rebuild the tt.

Comment: dbContext code generator is your POCO generator. It will create two files. One will be your .tt file that will have your POCOs and the other is your context.tt which essential defines how your POCOs are created. The context.tt file can be configured through your edmx (eg Lazy Loading etc).  DBContext is based off your old ObjectContext, but the POCOs are simpler.

Comment: @AshwinChandran , why can't you just move your Model.edmx node to Models folder? Code Generation Item creates duplicates to what already exists in this folder.

Answer (score 1):

Generate code like Poco give you classes that match your database(table)

Example : Database with two tables (Person and Child)

In your ItemPoco, you're going to have two classes Person and Child.
In this classes, their attributes are your Column's table.

Comment: You can get your data from your DB with a object which contain your row. Example : EMPLOYEE employee =  (from emp in EMPLOYEES where id == 1 select emp).FirstOrResult(); employee gonna be a object create by POCO, so you can easily use it.